# NetMQ Actor pattern

Tags: c#

I'm trying to have one WPF application to communicate with an other application when something change on the UI. For example : a slider changes and I send the new value or a textbox input change and I send the new input value.

The second application is listening and receive those changes to use them in some way, doesn't really matter how in this case.

To achieve this I'm using NetMQ following the Actor pattern example from the documentation : https://netmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/actor/

Right now I have these Client/Server class :

The Server :

```
public class NetMQServer
{
    public class ShimHandler : IShimHandler
    {
        private PairSocket shim;
        private NetMQPoller poller;
        private PublisherSocket publisher;

        public void Initialise(object state)
        {
        }

        public void Run(PairSocket shim)
        {
            using (publisher = new PublisherSocket())
            {
                publisher.Bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:7777");
                publisher.Options.SendHighWatermark = 1000;
                this.shim = shim;
                shim.ReceiveReady += OnShimReady;
                shim.SignalOK();
                poller = new NetMQPoller { shim, publisher };
                poller.Run();
            }
        }

        private void OnShimReady(object sender, NetMQSocketEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Publisher ShimReady");
            string command = e.Socket.ReceiveFrameString();
            switch (command)
            {
                case NetMQActor.EndShimMessage:
                    poller.Stop();
                    break;

                case "UpdateString":
                    string stringMessage = e.Socket.ReceiveFrameString();
                    publisher.SendMoreFrame("UpdateString").SendFrame(stringMessage);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void UpdateString(string stringmessage, string propertyToUpdate)
        {
            propertyToUpdate = stringmessage;
        }
    }

    private NetMQActor actor;

    public void Start()
    {
        if (actor != null)
            return;
        actor = NetMQActor.Create(new ShimHandler());
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (actor != null)
        {
            actor.Dispose();
            actor = null;
        }
    }

    public void SendStringMessage(string stringToSend)
    {
        if (actor == null)
            return;

        var message = new NetMQMessage();
        message.Append("UpdateString");
        message.Append(stringToSend);
        actor.SendMultipartMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Here when the property of a control change  I call `SendStringMessage(string stringToSend)` function and it is sending with the NetMQ publisher (the string is only for testing, I could send whatever object as byte too).

Anyway, here is the client running on the second app :

```
public class NetMQClient
{
    public StringMessage StringMessage { get; set; }
    public string ReceivedString { get; set; }
    public CerasSerializer Serializer { get; set; }

    public NetMQClient()
    {
        Serializer = new CerasSerializer();
        StringMessage = new StringMessage("");
    }

    public class ShimHandler : IShimHandler
    {
        private PairSocket shim;
        private NetMQPoller poller;
        private SubscriberSocket subscriber;
        private StringMessage stringMessage;

        public ShimHandler(StringMessage stringMessage)
        {
            this.stringMessage = stringMessage;
        }

        public void Initialise(object state)
        {
        }

        public void Run(PairSocket shim)
        {
            using (subscriber = new SubscriberSocket())
            {
                subscriber.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:7777");
                subscriber.Subscribe("UpdateString");
                subscriber.Options.ReceiveHighWatermark = 1000;
                subscriber.ReceiveReady += OnSubscriberReady;
                this.shim = shim;
                shim.ReceiveReady += OnShimReady;
                shim.SignalOK();
                poller = new NetMQPoller { shim, subscriber };
                poller.Run();
            }
        }

        private void OnSubscriberReady(object sender, NetMQSocketEventArgs e)
        {
            string topic = subscriber.ReceiveFrameString();

            if (topic == "UpdateString")
            {
                string received = subscriber.ReceiveFrameString();
                stringMessage.Message = received;
            }
        }

        private void OnShimReady(object sender, NetMQSocketEventArgs e)
        {
            string command = e.Socket.ReceiveFrameString();
            if (command == NetMQActor.EndShimMessage)
            {
                poller.Stop();
            }
        }
    }

    public string GetPayLoad()
    {
        return actor.ReceiveFrameString();
    }

    private NetMQActor actor;

    public void Start()
    {
        if (actor != null)
            return;
        actor = NetMQActor.Create(new ShimHandler(StringMessage));
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (actor != null)
        {
            actor.Dispose();
            actor = null;
        }
    }
}
```

So far this is working but there is something I'm really not sure I'm doing correctly. I'm using the `StringMessage` property inside `OnSubscriberReady` but is this really how it should be done ?

If the Server is sending through its Actor, shouldn't it be the same for Client ? receiving data through its actor as well ?

Thanks